# Tetris shape drop C++

Tags: c++

I am making a tetris game in C++. I am new to the language and need help displaying my tetris pieces in my bucket. Also if anyone wants to point out any improvements to me that would be greatly appreciated!

The "include" code was modified so that it would show up. The code I have so far I started as an 'outline' and I am adding the functions in one at a time.

Code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <ctime>

    using namespace std;


    //declare variables used in functions.
    string name;
    bool gameOver;
    int shapeArray[4][4];
    int tetrisShape;

    //This function gets the player's name.
   string getPlayerName()
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        cin >> name;
        return name;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }


    //This will initialize the bucket for the game.

     void initBucket(int x, int y)
    {
        HANDLE handle;
        COORD position;
        handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        position.X = x;
        position.Y = y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, position);
    }



         int initPieces()
       {

        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
        int randomNumber = rand();
        int shapeType = (randomNumber % 7);

        switch (shapeType)
       {
        case 0:
            shapeArray[0][0] = ' '; shapeArray[1][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][0]            = ' '; shapeArray[3][0] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][1] = ' '; shapeArray[1][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][1] = ' '; shapeArray[3][1] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][2] = ' '; shapeArray[1][2] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][2] = 'X'; shapeArray[3][2] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][3] = ' '; shapeArray[1][3] = ' '; shapeArray[2][3] = ' '; shapeArray[3][3] = ' '; 

case 1:
    shapeArray[0][0] = ' '; shapeArray[1][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][0] = ' '; shapeArray[3][0] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][1] = ' '; shapeArray[1][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][1] = ' '; shapeArray[3][1] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][2] = 'X'; shapeArray[1][2] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][2] = ' '; shapeArray[3][2] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][3] = ' '; shapeArray[1][3] = ' '; shapeArray[2][3] = ' '; shapeArray[3][3] = ' ';
case 2:
    shapeArray[0][0] = ' '; shapeArray[1][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][0] = ' '; shapeArray[3][0] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[1][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[3][1] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][2] = ' '; shapeArray[1][2] = ' '; shapeArray[2][2] = ' '; shapeArray[3][2] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][3] = ' '; shapeArray[1][3] = ' '; shapeArray[2][3] = ' '; shapeArray[3][3] = ' ';
case 3:
    shapeArray[0][0] = ' '; shapeArray[1][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][0] = ' '; shapeArray[3][0] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][1] = ' '; shapeArray[1][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][1] = ' '; shapeArray[3][1] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][2] = ' '; shapeArray[1][2] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][2] = ' '; shapeArray[3][2] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][3] = ' '; shapeArray[1][3] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][3] = ' '; shapeArray[3][3] = ' ';
case 4:
    shapeArray[0][0] = ' '; shapeArray[1][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[3][0] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][1] = ' '; shapeArray[1][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[3][1] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][2] = ' '; shapeArray[1][2] = ' '; shapeArray[2][2] = ' '; shapeArray[3][2] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][3] = ' '; shapeArray[1][3] = ' '; shapeArray[2][3] = ' '; shapeArray[3][3] = ' ';
case 5:
    shapeArray[0][0] = ' '; shapeArray[1][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[3][0] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][1] = ' '; shapeArray[1][1] = ' '; shapeArray[2][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[3][1] = 'X';
    shapeArray[0][2] = ' '; shapeArray[1][2] = ' '; shapeArray[2][2] = ' '; shapeArray[3][2] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][3] = ' '; shapeArray[1][3] = ' '; shapeArray[2][3] = ' '; shapeArray[3][3] = ' ';
case 6:
    shapeArray[0][0] = ' '; shapeArray[1][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][0] = 'X'; shapeArray[3][0] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[1][1] = 'X'; shapeArray[2][1] = ' '; shapeArray[3][1] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][2] = ' '; shapeArray[1][2] = ' '; shapeArray[2][2] = ' '; shapeArray[3][2] = ' ';
    shapeArray[0][3] = ' '; shapeArray[1][3] = ' '; shapeArray[2][3] = ' '; shapeArray[3][3] = ' ';
default:
    break;
}
return tetrisShape;
```

}

```
    //This function drops the game piece. It will do this without question the first time.
    //Each time after it whether or not a piece is dropped will depend on  the output of the gameOver function.
    void dropPiece(int tetrisShape)
    {
        cout << tetrisShape << endl;
    }

    //This function will allow the player to rotate the game pieces.
    void rotatePiece()
    {
        cout << "This function will rotate the piece" << endl;
    }

    //This function will determine if a line needs to be deleted.
   void deleteLine()
    {
        cout << "This function deletes lines." << endl;
    }

    //This function will add points as pieces are dropped and rows are deleted.
    void KeepScore()
    {
        cout << "This function will award x points for each piece that is dropped and x+y points for each row deleted." << endl;

    }


    bool isGameOver()
    {
        cout << "Before the next piece is dropped this function will check if the game is over." << endl;
        gameOver = true;
        return gameOver;
    }


    //This function will run after game over and it displays the player's name and their final score.
    void finalScore(string name)
   {
        cout << "This function will display the player's name and the final score" << endl;
        cout << name << " 'score'" << endl;
    }


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        string endGame = "no";


        //This loop is for the application
        while (endGame == "no")
        {
            name = getPlayerName();
            initBucket(0, 1);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 2);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 3);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 4);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 5);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 6);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 7);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 8);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 9);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 10);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 11);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 12);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 13);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 14);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 15);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 16);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 17);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 18);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 19);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 20);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 21);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 22);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 23);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 24);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(0, 25);
            cout << "#" << endl;



            initBucket(12, 1);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 2);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 3);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 4);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 5);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 6);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 7);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 8);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 9);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 10);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 11);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 12);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 13);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 14);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 15);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 16);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 17);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 18);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 19);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 20);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 21);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 22);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 23);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 24);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 25);
            cout << "#" << endl;

            initBucket(0, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(1, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(2, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(3, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(4, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(5, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(6, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(7, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(8, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(9, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(10, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(11, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;
            initBucket(12, 26);
            cout << "#" << endl;

            tetrisShape = initPieces();

            //This loop is for the game play.
            while (gameOver == false)
            {
                dropPiece(tetrisShape);
                rotatePiece();
                deleteLine();
                KeepScore();
                gameOver = isGameOver();



            }
            finalScore(name);
            cout << "Do you want to end the game: ";
            cin >> endGame;
        }



        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) This site is designed to help people with specific problems. You have a more general situation, which is better suited for some sort of discussion forum or maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a long path in front of you, but even the code written so far has many problems.

Let's see `int initPieces()` for example.

- It's supposed to return a number which correspond to the randomly
  chosen piece, but it returns `tetrisShape` a variable which is never
  even initialized.
- It uses `rand()` and calls `rands()` every time, which is a bad idea, it's better to seed the random number generator (there are also
  better and modern alternatives, like the functions in ) only
  one time (or few times) in the program.
- The way it initializes the global variable `shapeArray` is pretty unreadable.

Consider this snippet where a different approach is implemented:

```
#include <array>

using std::array;

using shape_t = std::array<std::array<char, 4>, 4>;

shape_t initPieces() 
{
    static array<shape_t, 7> pieces{{  
        {{  { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
        }},
        {{  { ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
        }},
        {{  { ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
        }},
        {{  { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
        }},
        {{  { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
        }},
        {{  { 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
        }},
        {{  { ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ' },
            { 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
        }}
    }};

    return pieces[rand() % pieces.size()];
}
```

Besides any further consideration about the gloabl design of the program in general and the main function in particular (it's a working progress), all the repeted calls to `initBucket()` in `main` are replaceable with a couple of loops and a little modification to that function itself (if you really need to do that way).

```
void initBucket( int x, int y, char c )
{
    HANDLE handle;
    COORD position;
    handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    position.X = x;
    position.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, position);
    std::cout << c;
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
srand(time(NULL));

for ( int i = 1; i < 26; ++ i ) {
    initBucket(0, i, '#');
    initBucket(12, i, '#');
}

for ( int i = 0; i < 13; ++ i ) {
    initBucket(i, 26, '#');
}

// ... other stuff ...

// initialize the falling piece:
shape_t shape = initPieces();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some tips:
Make multiple files and include them into you main file to get some order into this jungle of functions (I think even you dont get through these confusion anymore?)
In GetPlayerName(), the funtion is ending/returning before the

Comment: <<endl; command, so this wont execute anymore.
string endgame should be a boolean, not a string. Bool is made for such things.
Sorry, but you code is just horrible. In main function, initialising millions of Buckets? You could make a for loop, like
    for(int i=1;i<=25;i++){
    initBucket(0, i); //The init function depends on the actual value of i
    cout << "#" << endl;
    initBucket(12,i);
    cout<<"#"<<endl;
    }